# Collection ViewSource to filter listbox by typing in textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, listbox, collectionviewsource

I have a listbox in WPF where users firstname and lastname are listed.  I have a textbox, and I am trying to filter as I type by the names.  Here is what I am trying:  (Nothing is being filtered when I am typing in the textbox)

Here is my VM

```
        #region Members

        private CollectionViewSource usercvs = new CollectionViewSource();
        private string searchString;

        #endregion

        #region Properties

        public string SearchFilter
        {
            get
            {
                return this.searchString;
            }

            set
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.searchString))
                    AddFilter();

                usercvs.View.Refresh();    
                this.searchString = value;
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region Methods

        private void AddFilter()
        {
            usercvs.Filter -= new FilterEventHandler(Filter);
            usercvs.Filter += new FilterEventHandler(Filter);

        }

        private void Filter(object sender, FilterEventArgs e)
        {
            // see Notes on Filter Methods:
            var src = e.Item as User;
            if (src == null)
                e.Accepted = false;
            else if (src.LastName != null && !src.LastName.Contains(SearchFilter))
                e.Accepted = false;
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your ListBox bind to the property Users (ObservableCollection)?

Comment: Yes it does, sorry I should of put the listbox xaml in the code.  I will update the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an additional property to your ViewModel that exposes the CollectionViewSource and bind your ListBox to that property.

```
public CollectionViewSource FilteredUsers{
  get {
    return usercvs.View;
  }
}
```

The `ObservableCollection` is not changed when you apply any filters to the `CollectionViewSource`, so that you will always see all items. The Filter gets applied to the CollectionViewSource and the filtered result can be accessed by the property View of the class.

Comment: I made the property and when I set the listbox binding to the property nothing is being returned, but when I set breakpoints in the Filter methods the data is showing.

Answer (score 2):

Got it with this

```
 public ICollectionView FilteredUsers
        {
            get
            {
                return usercvs.View;
            }
        }
```

Comment: yes this is correct. I forgot to return the View of the CollectionViewSource